# htaccess: Force https:// to http:// on a single page

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

Due to a iframe on a particular page pulling content from a http:// domain, there is a conflict issue since my site is https://.

How do I get htaccess to revert to http on a particular page e.g: https://www.example.com/about is redirected to http://www.example.com/about

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying the conflict is because of the browser warning.  But in the end, an http downgrade will also generate a warning.  Your best course of actions are: Load the framed content over https if it is available, or open the framed content in a new tab or window.  Iframes are frowned upon in today's world, due to clickjacking and XSS exploits and there are some upcoming changes to browser that are going to make it extremely difficult to do (you will need the other domain to allow you to frame their content on your domain or the browser won't load it), so it's best to get away from it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(about)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(about)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What this does is first check if HTTPs is not on, if not, then it will forward everything to HTTPs except for the directory `about`. The second rule checks if HTTPs is on, if so then it will redirect `about` back to HTTP.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.